# How to convert PDO fetchAll result to JSON?

Tags: php, json, sql-server, pdo

I am fetching data from my MSSQL Server 2016 database using PDO in PHP.
Query works well:

```
try  {
    $db = new PDO( 'dblib:host='.$server.' ; dbname='.$database, $user, $pw);
    $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) );
}

$smt = $db->query("SELECT ABP.cArtNr AS 'Artikelnummer',
       MAX(SUBSTRING(ABP.cName,8,50)) AS 'Beschreibung',
       SUM(ABP.nQuantityPurchased) AS 'Anzahl',
       SUM(ABP.nQuantityPurchased) * MAX(AA.fPrice) AS 'Brutto-Umsatz'
FROM pf_amazon_bestellung
INNER JOIN pf_amazon_bestellungpos ABP ON pf_amazon_bestellung.kAmazonBestellung = ABP.kAmazonBestellung
INNER JOIN pf_amazon_angebot AA ON ABP.cArtNr = AA.cSellerSKU
WHERE dPurchaseDate >= DateAdd(DAY, DateDiff(DAY, 0, getDate()), 0)
  AND pf_amazon_bestellung.cOrderStatus <> 'Canceled'
GROUP BY ABP.cArtNr");

while(($o = $smt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== false) {
    print_r($o);
}
$db = NULL;
```

You can see the result here: http://stats.valonic.com/server_processing4.php

This result is not usable for me, as I need a JSON which needs to have the structure shown here: http://stats.valonic.com/server_processing.php
Here I used the following code:

```
$a = array();
while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $a['data'][] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($a);
```

But I'd like to use PDO instead.

I tried using fetchAll instead:

```
$result = $smt->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

Result of that can be seen here: http://stats.valonic.com/server_processing3.php
Okay, works, but don't know how to convert the result to reach a structure like shown in http://stats.valonic.com/server_processing.php.

Can you help me out here?
Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: `json_encode(['data' => $result]);`

Comment: Or even `json_encode(['data' => $smt->fetchAll()]);`

Comment: Thank you! I tried your corrected version - just white page in the result: echo json_encode(['data' => $smt->fetchAll()]);

Comment: Did your `print_r($result);` show any data?

Comment: Did you remove/comment out the `$result = $smt->fetchAll();` you run before the `json_encode()` If not that will have consumed all the results, before you do that in the `json_encode()` statement

Comment: Yes, this is the script which will give just white blank page: https://pastebin.com/LdeMQZcy Result can be seen here: http://stats.valonic.com/server_processing2.php

Comment: And yes, `print_r($result);` shows a good result, you can see the result of `print_r($result);` here: http://stats.valonic.com/server_processing3.php
Here i removed line 25 of the code seen on pastebin and inserted 
`$result = $smt->fetchAll();
print_r($result);`

Comment: Strange... I don't see any problems here, but still - blank page :( Do you have any other ideas @RiggsFolly ?
When echo-ing without json_encode, I just receive "Array" als result. Mh.

Comment: Change it to use comment 1 syntax and see if that helps

Comment: Jepp, tried it, doesn't help :( 
`$result = $smt->fetchAll(); 
echo json_encode(['data' => $result]);`

Comment: Then there is something else going on here. There is no reason as far as I can tell that this code should not work.

Comment: Okay - thank you for your time and help here!